# .htaccess directory protection not working in nginx

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I try to protect my dev web project a bit and add directory protection. ("Verzeichnisschutz" in german).

---

This is my `.htaccess` file (*project/.htaccess*)

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter the valid auth details"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

---

This is my `.htpasswd` file (*project/.htpasswd*)

```
test:$apr1$3RWv80vU$MJFZn3DHhrB8yPNO6/TDV.
```

---

But I can still enter the website without having to enter any credentials.
I tried different browsers and inspector/private mode.

What is wrong?

Comment: is right, instead check how the ngx_http_access_module works here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html Some usefull examples: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know why it does not work.

It is because my project runs on a **nginx** server and `.htaccess` does only work with apache.